# Docker контейнеры, php и exec() – как держать 1 процесс в 1 контейнере?

Tags: php, архитектура, docker

Веб-сервис принимает загруженный пользователем файл, что-то с ним делает в php, запуская через `exec()` пару внешних утилит – `ffprobe` и `ffmpeg`, и записывает что-то в MySQL и Redis.

Пытаюсь обернуть этот сервис в контейнеры. Легко, если костыльно: просто контейнер с php-fpm, в него доставляю расширения для Redis и статический билд `ffmpeg` и `ffprobe`. Плюс контейнеры с Nginx, Redis и MySQL.

Но ведь рекомендуется «один контейнер – один процесс».  Как мне держать `ffmpeg` в отдельном контейнере и обращаться к нему из контейнера с `php-fpm`?

Comment: *один контейнер – один процесс* — наверно, всё-таки, скорее «один демон». который в процессе работы может запускать всё, что необходимо. в том числе, например, других «демонов» (популярный случай — supervisord). // а как «демонизировать» ffmpeg, и надо ли это вообще делать?

Comment: Не один процесс, а один родительский процесс. Форки и чайлды вполне себе разрешены до тех пор, пока это временные, а не бесконечные процессы. Вызывать внешний executable для возвращения результата - нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку **`ffmpeg`** и **`ffprobe`** сами по себе ни с кем общаться не могут, им в любом случае потребуется кто-то, кто будет разговаривать с внешним миром и передавать оттуда **этим двоим** задания.

Согласно философии **Docker** запускать в каждом контейнере только один процесс надо ради лёгкости *горизонтального масштабирования*: чтобы если сервис не справляется, его можно было продублировать. Чтобы принцип был проще для понимания, рекомендуется делать "один процесс на контейнер", но... **Первопричина** всё же важнее, а принцип на деле чуть сложнее.

На практике "агент" над парой процессов вполне может считаться отдельным сервисом, достойным размещаться в одном контейнере. "Агент" вполне может быть написан и на PHP, лишь бы не хранил своё "состояние" (входные данные могли поступать к любому обработчику, а выходные шли наружу).

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg - не сервис (если ты запускаешь его через командную строку/вызов system() ), а приложение

философия докера для масштабирования - один сервис/один контейнер,  а не одно приложение/один контейнер.

поэтому ты просто ставишь ffmpeg в том контейнере который его использует.

если, допустим, у тебя существует ffmpeg-сервер, который получает какие-то данные по сети, обрабатывает их и отдает обратно  - тогда да - можешь его запихнуть в другой контейнер. Сервер, который конвертит поток видео, например и по сети его отдает.

если ты конвертируешь какие-то отдельные файлы просто вызывая ffmpeg как программу - новый контейнер не нужен (и практически не возможен без костылей типа расшаренных директорий)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно создать многопоточных демонов рекомендую использовать паттерн - Объектный пул (Object pool) 
[Object Pool example GitHub](https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/tree/master/Creational/Pool)